# Power BI - DistinctCount with conditions does not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have a table and I need to add the different values that are greater than 5 and belong to the DEV team.

Unfortunately, it is not working.

I used this code, the expected result is 6 but now is showing only 3.

```
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT('data (1)'[issue_key]);
FILTER('data (1)';[team]="Dev");
FILTER('data (1)';[SLAs]>5)
)
```

[image: Table example]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this has to do with the row-context to filter-context [transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) induced by `CALCULATE`.

Try removing the row context with `ALL`:

```
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'data (1)'[issue_key] );
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'data (1)' ); [team] = "Dev" && [SLAs] > 5 )
)
```